# How do I get the type wrapped by a Promise type in flow?

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

This is a skeleton of what I'm after

```js
// @flow strict

const myFn = () => Promise.resolve(5);

const anotherNumber: ???<typeof myFn> = 6;
```

I'd like to get the type of the thing wrapped by the promise, and get that as a type - in this case, `number`.

I'm unable to come up with any flow utility method magic to do this :(

Comment: to "get" the resolved value of a Promise, you require to be inside a `.then` - or use `async/await` - I can't help with how that translates to what you want, but now you know how to "get" the value, I'm sure you can add some flesh to your skeleton

Comment: That's a runtime requirement - maybe it's a flow requirement too, but since it's a _static_ type checker, I was thinking it might be possible to get this info anyway

Comment: @Mark I've fixed your question title to make it clear that you want to extract a type, not access the fulfilment value of a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Flow's [`$Call` utility type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-call) to extract the `Promise` value from your function,

```
// You can also use `typeof myFn` in place of `MyFn`,
// but I prefer to be explicit with function types
type MyFn = void => Promise<number>;
const myFn: MyFn = () => Promise.resolve(5);

// Given a function that returns a Promise<R>, return R
// Example: given a function that returns `Promise<number>`, this returns `number`
type ExtractReturnPromiseValue = <R>(() => Promise<R>) => R;
const anotherNumber: $Call<ExtractReturnPromiseValue, MyFn> = 6;
const notAnotherNumber: $Call<ExtractReturnPromiseValue, MyFn> = false; // Error!
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEE0HsFdQYwIYDtQIDYGdKmhgpqAAYAuAngA56QBmoAtqQGJKGgCWK5aCcBNRAWSYsANACgQoAEbRioAJKhyAJzzU8y0MWxSCeAB5c2cNnIDupgBahq0JHGJtIKMpQxjXBIc1ABeUABukGwAJn4AfKAACsqQdGz4ADxI0HS6yuEA3GJwzhhyDMwAXKDeKP4AFACUEdGx8fgAdKpYaAF4FQCsVdkSYADibO0oCDZ2Dk4ulghyqsTQykgYqHVxCXiJAErhIqBzCyibfaAAovoIdFx4JQDmQ3gjY-aOzlrTs3jzi8uEMWtJKTSGnChF2xEsCT2nwOP0B6UIHgoBDOxGUPGIm2hiz+DTwADV0NACP4tuEKtVajj1qSar5IptsrklnJkJBwRoAHKpdIlAAkAGF0GhEii0Q5MV8kFT8AS0ETdmVIv4AGyMvJyJBsgCCmvZyi5QOUfMFaGFovREoO0vxhLwCuESps6HwmVAkhOyliygAhEA)

Comment: I took this and combined this all into a one-liner – perhaps it's useful:

`type $UnwrapPromise<V> = $Call<<U>(() => Promise<U>) => U, () => V>`

Comment: Sorry, make that `type $UnwrapPromise<V> = $Call<<U>(Promise<U>) => U, V>`.